# Meaning of もつて in the 割賦販売法

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of "もつて" in article 1 of the 割賦販売法?

「この法律は、割賦販売等に係る取引の公正の確保、購入者等が受けることのある損害の防止及びクレジットカード番号等の適切な管理等に必要な措置を講ずることにより、割賦販売等に係る取引の健全な発達を図るとともに、購入者等の利益を保護し、あわせて商品等の流通及び役務の提供を円滑にし、**もつて**国民経済の発展に寄与することを目的とする。」

Does it function similarly to ～をもって?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[以]{もっ}て can function as a 接続詞. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%A5%E3%81%A6_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%29/#jn-219462):

> もっ‐て【▽以て】
> 2⃣［接］《漢文における「以」や「式」の訓読から生じた語》そして。それによって。それについて。
> 「天地の間にあるよろずの物を資り、―衣食住の用を達し」〈福沢・学問のすゝめ〉

It can mean それで、それによって、"thereby". もって (以て, not 持って) sounds pretty literary. Writing it as も**つ**て makes it look even more literary and antiquated.