# Reading of もつて and であつて in legal texts

Tags: formality, archaic-language, legal

While reading the 特許法, I came across the following articles:

**第一条**　この法律は、発明の保護及び利用を図ることにより、発明を奨励し、`もつて`産業の発達に寄与することを目的とする。

**第六条**　法人でない社団又は財団`であつて`、代表者又は管理人の定めがあるものは、その名において次に掲げる手続をすることができる。

Referring to [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100945/meaning-of-%E3%82%82%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A6-in-the-%E5%89%B2%E8%B3%A6%E8%B2%A9%E5%A3%B2%E6%B3%95), these expressions apparently are formal ways to write 以て and であって, respectively.

My question is: if I were to read these articles aloud, would I pronounce もつて as もつて or as もって? Similar for であつて.

Comment: Related [When/why would one write a word using 直音表記?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I were to read these articles aloud, would I pronounce もつて as もつて or as もって? Similar for であつて.

Yes. The large つ in older texts is just following older orthography (usually called 歴史的仮名遣い). The pronunciation is the same: you can always read つ as っ. (Same for や・ゆ・よ.)

Note that the large つ is not completely mandatory for old orthography in general ([source](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1261274.html)). But regarding laws, apparently, they are required to follow the older orthography as long as the original articles are written with large つ etc. (see [this](https://siragagori.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/01/%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8E%E3%81%A4%E3%80%8F%E3%81%A8%E5%B0%8F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8E%E3%81%A3%E3%80%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4) for details).